# People can agree to doing this work

Tags: prepositions, gerunds

**Is it correct to say "people can agree to doing this work"?**

I have always seen people saying "people can agree to do this work", I don't know if this sentence is correct because I think that ***to*** is a preposition in the sentence "people can agree to doing this work" and ***to*** should be followed by a gerund (doing). Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

The verb **agree** accepts infinitive complements after a for ... to complementiser:

> (a1) I agreed for Jill to go.

When the subject of the infinitive is the same as that of the main verb, there is obligatory deletion of the second [mention of the] subject:

> (a2) I / they agreed to work / go.   //   I / they agreed to do this work.

[see [Analyzing Syntax and Semantics ... Virginia A. Heidinger](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=IIs3wjjkk4YC&pg=PA180&lpg=PA180&dq=agree+catenating+verb&source=bl&ots=ClmMAhDSIU&sig=dlkw6jAfR8zUzEBBS0oyOqvBRQQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwir48KynsfPAhWiOsAKHYx3D8UQ6AEIJTAB#v=onepage&q=agree%20catenating%20verb&f=false)]

On the other hand, **agree to** may be used as a transitive multi-word verb taking a regular noun phrase

> (b) The store owner agreed to the supplier's new proposal for a weekly
>   shipment.

an obvious gerund

> (c) If you don't agree to my leaving early, I'll just do it anyway.

or a less obviously identifiable ing-form fairly near the nounal end of the continuum

> (d) I cannot agree to going with you on such a dangerous adventure!

[(b) and (c) from the [McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/agree+to) and (d) from [The American Heritage® Dictionary of Phrasal Verbs](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/agree+to).]